# How to read excel data in the format column and its value and it should come in json structure

Tags: java

[image]

In the attached excel, I want read the data and display in the below `json` format:

```
test id : value
desc :  value
execution status : value
execution browser : value
```

Any suggestions ???

i tried below code but it is populating only the first column and its value.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            String cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString();
    if (null != cell) {
            //String TC_ID = String.valueOf(row.getCell(0));
                String data = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).toString();
                map.put(cell, data);

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        list.add(map);
        fis.close();
        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(excelPath);
        workSheet.write(output_file);
        output_file.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return list;
}
```

Comment: To read excel files with java refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file

Comment: Read about how to read Excel files: [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org/), then implement the read and then read about the next step, which is putting the data read into JSON format.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44002379/7562674

Comment: And to make objects to Json format this is a very good tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795100/how-can-i-get-excel-data-and-convert-it-to-json

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache POI (https://poi.apache.org).
Look at this: https://github.com/nullpunkt/excel-to-json

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CSVToJson {

    private static String pathname = "path-to-file.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File(pathname);
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(input);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                new File(input.getParent(), input.getName().replace(".csv", ".json"))));

        CSVParser parse = CSVParser.parse(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                .withTrim());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<String> headers = parse.getHeaderNames();

        System.out.println("Headers: " + headers);
        for (CSVRecord record : parse) {
            ObjectNode object = mapper.createObjectNode();
            for (String header : headers) {
                String value = record.get(header);
                object.put(header, value);
            }
            writer.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(object));
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

You would need the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for ur support. I am writing a controller also and using type as json, so code is not required to convert it. The only concern is getting the column names with all the values in the json format. Let me know if it makes sense.